# How to get PHP object data?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have these data formats of objects in php.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [currency] => JPY
            [rate] => 136.07
        )

)
```

How can I get currency and rate from this object? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Seems like an SimpleXMLElment, are you sure it is a stdClass ?

Comment: Yeah I have converted Xml data in to object..  And can't figure out further more..

Comment: Use the keywords which you have. Google: `PHP access XML attributes` :)

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote my question? Though this is unique problem for beginners..

Comment: And for downvoters, How can you get japanese currency rate from http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that so you can just call

```
$object->attributes()->currency;
```

Answer (score 2):

If that object is named $obj, it's `$currencyValue=$obj->{'@attributes'}->currency;`

Comment: *Err.* OP has two stdClass objects inside of each other

Comment: Someone has downvoted your answer but it worked for me..  Thanks dude..  I have upvoted it..

Answer (score 0):

Try these.. ..presuming that you are using SimpleXML to parse the data.

```
$currency = $object->attributes()->currency;
$rate     = $object->attributes()->rate;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it not seems to work..  @RightClick 's answer seems to work fine..

Comment: If you have declared the object as a SimpleXML Object, then this will work fine.

Comment: @AnilChaudhari Don't convert your xml object into a stdClass object.

Comment: @MaggsWeb Yeah I have used SimpleXML .. Here is my snipped  `$fileContents= file_get_contents($url);

  $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);

  $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

  $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);

  $json = json_encode($simpleXml);`